# libgdx - ShapeRenderer in Group.draw renders in wrong colour

Tags: java, colors, libgdx

**MyGroup**:

```
public class GShape extends Group{
private ShapeRenderer shape;

public GShape() {
    super();
    shape = new ShapeRenderer();
}

@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    shape.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    Gdx.gl10.glLineWidth(5);
    shape.setColor(1, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    shape.line(0, 0, 200, 100);
    shape.end();
}
}
```

**Main**:

```
public class GameControl implements ApplicationListener {
private Stage stage;
private GShape gShape;

@Override
public void create() {
    stage = new Stage(480,320,false);

    Texture t = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/the200.png"));
    Image i = new Image(t);
    stage.addActor(i);
    gShape = new GShape();
    stage.addActor(gShape);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.draw();
//  gShape.render();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
}
```

Colour of shape is not white? Why?

http://nw7.upanh.com/b3.s38.d3/352dd792eb77ce6df204a7af47ae1ac6_55348087.cos.jpg?rand=0.19125773780979216

Answer (score 13):

You are probably getting inconsistent results because you're mixing `SpriteBatch` and `ShapeRenderer` contexts.  Both of these expect state they "store" in OpenGL to be maintained between `begin()` and `end()` calls.

The `Actor` `draw()` method is called in a context where the `SpriteBatch` `begin()` has already been called, so you need to end it before beginning your `ShapeRenderer`.  (And you need to restart the `SpriteBatch` before returning.

Like this:

```
@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
  super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
  batch.end();   //  ** End the batch context
  shape.begin(ShapeType.Line);
  // .. draw lines ...
  shape.end()
  batch.begin(); // ** Restart SpriteBatch context that caller assumes is active
}
```

Comment: Just a side note, if you call begin() and end() a large number of times (100s) per frame, you will notice a huge performance hit on many android devices.