# Drawing a transparent shape in libGDX as an Actor?

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to draw a simple rect on the screen in a class and using it as an actor.

But whatever I do, it seems that there is no option to draw it transparent. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

```
public class AreaColorRect extends Actor {

    public float opacity = 0.0f;
    private Color shapeFillColor = new Color();
    public Rectangle area;
    public ShapeRenderer shapeRen;

    public AreaColorRect(float x, float y, float w, float h) {
        shapeRen = new ShapeRenderer();
        this.area = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        shapeRen.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRen.setColor(new Color(shapeFillColor.r, shapeFillColor.g, shapeFillColor.b,
            0.0f));
        shapeRen.rect(area.x, area.y, area.width, area.height);
        shapeRen.end();
    }

    public void setShapeFillColor(float r, float g, float b) {
        this.shapeFillColor = new Color(r, g, b, 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing contexts.  End your `SpriteBatch` before starting the `ShapeRenderer`.  See [libgdx - ShapeRenderer in Group.draw renders in wrong colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381106/libgdx-shaperenderer-in-group-draw-renders-in-wrong-colour).  This might not be the problem, though.

You also need to turn on blending.  You can just do this once globally, or enable it as necessary (and disable it).  It should be enabled by the `SpriteBatch` context, but I don't think its enabled for the `ShapeRenderer`.

```
Gdx.graphics.getGL10().glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND); // Or GL20
```

The order you render your background and Actors also makes a difference for transparency.

Finally, you've set the opacity to 0, so the object will be completely invisible.  That generally doesn't do anything at all.  (I assume you're just trying to get a change from the current 100% visible?)

Comment: Well, its true that the opacity-/ alpha-value is still wrong. But this was just because I was testing different values.
The problem still exists. I do some changes (like ending the spritebatch at first) but the rect still appears. Even when alpha is still at 0.0f

Comment: As P.T. mentioned, it looks like you have blending disabled when executing that code. Note: by default when you call end() on SpriteBatch it will ensure blending is disabled.

Comment: does `Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);`have to be called within render() or just once within the Screen's constructor ?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for digging this up. Since you are tagging Android, though, I thought I would just chip in my experiences.
I recently spent almost 4 hours on a problem, where alpha blending just wasn't working, as it isn't for you.

Turned out that libgdx' `AndroidApplicationConfiguration` uses 0 bit for alpha channel as default.
If this is the case for you, too, it might be worth changing that to something more sensible before you `initialize()` your app.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you've written... do you mean something like this? `AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();` `config.a = 1;` `initialize(new MainGame(), config);` ?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Yes, exactly. Although I'd recommend `config.a = 8`, as those are the number of bits used for the alpha channel.

Answer (score 2):

I just decided to use Scene2d for my game and reached the same question: how to use a rectangle as an actor and draw it on the screen?

Then i found this piece of documentation on the [libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) 
(By default the Scene2d has a SpriteBatch that handles drawing of the actors)

> If an actor needs to perform drawing differently, such as with a
>   ShapeRenderer, the Batch should be ended and then begun again at the
>   end of the method. Of course, this causes the batch to be flushed, so
>   should be used judiciously. The transformation and projection matrices
>   from the Batch can be used:

```
private ShapeRenderer renderer = new ShapeRenderer();

public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.end();

    renderer.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
    renderer.setTransformMatrix(batch.getTransformMatrix());
    renderer.translate(getX(), getY(), 0);

    renderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    renderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    renderer.end();

    batch.begin();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked fine for me...  (with correct transform in Group)