# Libgdx Mesh rendering along with stage

Tags: libgdx, mesh, stage

i am trying to render a textured mesh along with stage in Libgdx. I have problem rendering texture when i put the `stage.draw` on top of `mesh.render()`.

**Case 1:**

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
    texture.bind();
    mesh.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

}

// -- This is in my create method:
        mesh = new Mesh(true, 3, 3, 
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, "a_position"),
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorPacked, 4, "a_color"),
                new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, "a_texCoords"));

        mesh.setVertices(new float[] { 50, 50, 0,Color.toFloatBits(255, 0, 0, 255),0,1,
                                        50, 500, 0,Color.toFloatBits(0, 255, 0, 255),0,0,
                                        500, 50, 0, Color.toFloatBits(0, 0, 255, 255),1,1                                                   });

        mesh.setIndices(new short[] { 0, 1, 2 });
```

In the above case I am not able to render texture but able to render gradient triangle.

**Case 2:**

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    texture.bind();
    mesh.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}
```

In this case i am able to render texture properly on the triangle.

**My Questions:**

1. Why does the order of `stage.draw()` and `mesh.render()` affect the texture although I can draw the triangle.
2. How do I draw the mesh with a texture in an actor's `draw` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is a a "stateful" library (so changes made by calls into OpenGL persist until changed again).  So, something in the `stage.draw()` call is changing the OpenGL state that makes your mesh's textures not work.

You might try moving the:

```
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

call down with your:

```
texture.bind();
mesh.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

I didn't think the Stage would un-enable texturing, but it looks like it might.

Additionally, if you're trying to draw meshes directly from within an Actor's `draw` callback, you may need to `end` the `batch` and restart around your non-batch drawing.  The batch construction makes assumptions about OpenGL state between its `begin` and `end` calls, so it may get confused if you change the state.  See [libgdx - ShapeRenderer in Group.draw renders in wrong colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381106/libgdx-shaperenderer-in-group-draw-renders-in-wrong-colour?rq=1) for a related example.

Comment: Thank you that works. Seems like stage disables the texture binding somewhere in its logic.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry, this is just a guess: try adding

```
Gdx.gl10.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
```

between drawing mesh and stage, or after, or before... i had a similar problem, where i wanted to use shaders and BitmapFonts

Comment: The Libgdx `texture.bind()` call should accomplish that.